# PHP COM and C# "Out" and boolean Parameters

Tags: c#, php

I'm connecting through PHP "COM" to an API that is compatible with C#,C++ etc.
I have successfully made connection with the application and trying to use "out" parameters through COM and getting a "type mismatch" error.  Is the "out" parameter and is supposed to house the response and then the false. I'm not sure if it fails on that or if it fails on the false.. but either way I can't get this to work.

the C# example looks like this:

```
EdmViewInfo[] Views = null;
vault.GetVaultViews( out Views, false );
```

the php code looks like this:

```
$this->epdm = new COM('ConisioLib.EdmVault') or die("Cannot open vault.");

...

$this->aviews = array();      
try {

         $this->epdm->GetVaultViews($this->aviews, False );

   } catch (Exception $e) {

        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";

 }
```

I get the following returned errors:
Caught exception: Parameter 1: Type mismatch.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: How is the `epdm` field initialized? Is it an actual PHP `COM` class instance or something else? (e.g. a wrapper layer around PHP `COM` class calls?)

Comment: '$this->epdm = new COM('ConisioLib.EdmVault') or die("Cannot open vault.");'   That is the initialization.  

The connection initializes and I can login and grab some basic info, so I do know it works.

'EdmViewInfo[] Views = null; 
vault.GetVaultViews(out Views, false);'   
C# example sorry, above was VB

Answer (score 0):

I'm not intimately familiar with PHP's COM extension, but I did some research online that suggests to use COM `[out]` parameters in PHP you use the `&` operator so PHP uses pass-by-reference semantics:

```
$arr = array();
$com = new COM( 'ConisioLib.EdmVault' ) or die( "Cannot open vault." );
$com->GetVaultViews( &$arr, false );
```

Note that even though `$arr` would be completely overwritten by the `[out]` parameter you still need to initialize `$arr` to a native PHP `array` type so the COM marshalling layer knows what types its dealing with.

Comment: Thanks Dai, I get the following error: Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed.  What is interesting is it looks like the "type missmatch" error is on parameter 1 (the "false") in the statement.  It calls for it but don't know why this is failing... php should be casting these variables correctly right?

Comment: Are you sure "parameter 1" is zero-based and that it doesn't refer to the "array" parameter instead?

Comment: I'm not sure and don't know how to tell.  I've tried to mess with the variables to see if that Parameter 1 changes.  It turns to 0 if I remove an argument but then gives an error that it is expecting 2 arguments.   There is surprisingly very little information on the COM extension.  I imagine that I'm not the only one that has had this problem.  I hope I don't have to abandon this notion and go with making a .net app instead.

Answer (score -1):

It appears the two 'Array' types you are referencingf are not the same.  ONe has a capital letter and the other does not.  IN addition, what you reference as a C# example, looks more like VB.NET.  It may be best to check the case of all your references to Array to make sure they are found.  What editor are you using?

Comment: there is only one array in the out parameter. I haven't gotten an error on the array part, its the "False" part im getting the error for some reason.   The in parameter is just false or False.  It doesn't seem to matter.